# E185: Cannot find color scheme*

Tags: vim, color-scheme

I have been customizing my vimrc file but for some reason, no colorschemes work. Whenever I try to change the colorscheme, it just gives me:

```
E185: Cannot find color scheme '*'
```

I checked the `color` folder to make sure I actually have colors and I do. For example the first item in the `color` folder is `blue.vim` but when I put `colorscheme blue` in the vimrc, it just gives

```
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'blue'
```

when I start Vim and the colorscheme doesn't apply. I also tried changing the colorscheme from within Vim and it also returns the same error. All the other vimrc settings that I've tried work so far.

Comment: What do you mean? The colorschemes I've tried are in the color folder.

Comment: make sure you have rgb.txt in your $VIMRUNTIME path

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt  I am having the same problem, and I remember that, when trying to set up sway a while back, I was unable to do so, because "value not set for XDG_RUNTIME " or something like that (its been quite a while ago, so I do not remember specifics.) I ended up giving up, as I didn't know what value to set it to.  I am sure now that this extends from the same issue. I believe you were on the right path. Maybe this will add the needed context. Maybe vim runtime points to xdg runtime?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This sounds like a problem with your `'runtimepath'` option. If you use a plugin manager, these usually extend that. The default location should be `~/.vim/colors`. Please check with

```
:set runtimepath?
```

There should be a `~/.vim` in there (or equivalent).

If all else fails, you could also just `:source /full/path/to/your/color.vim`

Comment: 'runtimepath=~/vimfiles,~\Desktop/vimfiles,~\Desktop,~\Desktop/vimfiles/after,~
/vimfiles/after,~/vim80/bundle/Vundle.vim'

Comment: set runtimepath gives me: 'runtimepath=~/vimfiles,~\Desktop/vimfiles,~\Desktop,~\Desktop/vimfiles/after,~
/vimfiles/after,~/vim80/bundle/Vundle.vim'                                                     not sure what I'm supposed to do with that? :source C:\full path to\colors gives me: E484: Can't open file C:\full path to\colors

Comment: So, where is your colorscheme script? In `colors/name.vim` in one of the directories in runtimepath? Did you use the actual path (not the example) with `:source`? If the file path exists, there shouldn't be a E484 error. Also, I notice you're using Vundle. Have you put the `:color blue` after the Vundle initialization?

Comment: Thank you so much! sorry it took so long to understand what you were saying.

Comment: Trying to add the darcula scheme I came to this page, turns out I was typing d**ra**cula mistakenly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. For others looking here, the actual command is `set runtimepath+=~/.vim`.

Comment: I ran `:set runtimepath?` and I get a list with `~/.vim` as first entry. Now, what? Some people are claiming they understood, but someone who is new to Vim, won't. Can anyone please elaborate complete steps? I still see empty list on doing CTRL + D after typing `:colorscheme`

Comment: @HalfWebDev: It really depends on where you put the colorscheme / where you installed it. In general, `'runtimepath'` has to contain the directory part in its list, and then the actual colorscheme is in a `colors/colorschemename.vim` subdir/file inside it. That's how is comes together.

Comment: It was a missing space after colorscheme to do CTRL+D. Happens only in iTerm.

Answer (score 53):

For those using Plug as plugin manager, the problem may be solved by setting the color scheme after declaring the plugin that provides the theme:

```
call plug#begin()
Plug 'rakr/vim-one'   " tell Vim to load the theme/plugin
call plug#end()

colorscheme one       " set the color scheme after the theme provider has been loaded
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a lifesaver!

Comment: i'm organizing configs by different files and your solution worked for me!
Thank you!

Comment: You saved my day!!!! Lual for president!

Answer (score 3):

For me it worked by removing the extension from the colorscheme file.

Try to rename `blue.vim` to `blue`.

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this error. The problem in my case was that the name of the colorscheme in the file was different from the file name. Renaming the colorscheme in the file fixed it for me.

In COLOR1.vim:

```
let g:colors_name = "COLOR2"
```

Changing to:

```
let g:colors_name = "COLOR1"
```

fixed the problem.

I assume that changing the file name would also fix this.

Comment: In my case, the filename was `editplus.vim` and in the file it was `let colors_name = "EditPlus"`. This worked fine in my Mac, but failed to work when I switched to Linux. I believe this is because Linux is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

This may also be due to entries/artifacts in your configuration files (~/.vimrc,system vimrc), or if you use the "vim -u ..." command line option to point to a custom configuration file.
The artifacts could be something like:
`set rtp -=$HOME/.vimrc`
`set rtp -=$HOME/.vimrc/after`
`set runtimepath -= $HOME/.vimrc`
...etc...
If you find these entries in your configuration files, then comment them out to see if the error goes away.
These are often entries in test configurations of vim to be used only in special instances. If you used such a test configuration file as the template for your routine vim configuration, then they are likely uneccessary.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was:
  (1) Download color scheme from [150 colors](https://github.com/luckydev/150colors) for example
   Reference: [Vim Color Scheme](https://vimcolorschemes.com/)

(2) Move the files in "colors" folder from (1) to "/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/colors/"
   Folder looks like depending on OS. CentOS has in this folder not like "~/.vim/colors/" in Ubuntu OS.
   Reference: [Ingo Karket's suggestion above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40082974/5595995), [Caleb's post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/410164/371914), [Enrico's note](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/243156/371914)

(3) Add line of `colorscheme <color scheme>` at "~/.vimrc"
   Please, match upper and lower case of the color scheme in "colors" folder

Runtime environment:
  OS: CentOS 7.9
  Computer: Intel Nuc