# Set a vim colorscheme for all users

Tags: vim

I want to set gruvbox as the default color scheme globally, for all users, but I can't get this working. I get `E185: Cannot find color scheme*`, but this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40077211/e185-cannot-find-color-scheme#) doesn't work for me. (I'm trying to do this in `vim`, not `gvim`).

I have gruvbox installed in `/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs/gruvbox`. My `/etc/vimrc` is a modification of the vimrc I used on my Windows desktop, but now I run it in Linux:

```
" All system-wide defaults are set in $VIMRUNTIME/archlinux.vim (usually just
" /usr/share/vim/vimfiles/archlinux.vim) and sourced by the call to :runtime
" you can find below.  If you wish to change any of those settings, you should
" do it in this file (/etc/vimrc), since archlinux.vim will be overwritten
" everytime an upgrade of the vim packages is performed.  It is recommended to
" make changes after sourcing archlinux.vim since it alters the value of the
" 'compatible' option.

" This line should not be removed as it ensures that various options are
" properly set to work with the Vim-related packages.
runtime! archlinux.vim

" If you prefer the old-style vim functionalty, add 'runtime! vimrc_example.vim'
" Or better yet, read /usr/share/vim/vim80/vimrc_example.vim or the vim manual
" and configure vim to your own liking!

" do not load defaults if ~/.vimrc is missing
"let skip_defaults_vim=1

" Make vim portable, well, not portable in linux yet
" let $HOME=$VIM

" Set color scheme
set t_Co=256
syntax on
colorscheme gruvbox
set background=dark
highlight Comment cterm=bold

" Setup Vimplugs
call plug#begin('/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs')
Plug 'vim-python/python-syntax'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'tmhedberg/SimpylFold'
Plug 'vim/killersheep'
Plug 'gruvbox-community/gruvbox'
call plug#end()
```

This is my `runtimepath`:

```
runtimepath=~/.vim,/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs/python-syntax,/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs/nerdcommenter,/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs/SimpylFold,/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs/killersheep,/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs/gruvbox,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim82,/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,~/.vim/after
```

`vim --version` shows these search paths:

```
   system vimrc file: "/etc/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Try moving `colorscheme gruvbox` at the very end of `/etc/vimrc`. I suspect `/usr/share/vim/vim82/plugs` is added to `runtimepath` after `call plug#begin(…)`

Comment: @phd after `plug#end()` actually... Yeah, the `colorscheme gruvbox` needs to come after that line. Managing plug-ins with vim-plug for multiple users is somewhat questionable... But that's another story.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried to put the `colorscheme gruvbox` behind `call plug#end()`, but it still could not load, same error. Do you think I should remove the plugins from /usr/share and have them installed in each user's home instead?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem like this:

1. Open root console (`su`)
2. Uninstall all Vimplug plugins
3. Restart `vim`
4. Reinstall `gruvbox`
5. Restart `vim`
6. Reinstall the rest of the plugins

Before I installed the Plugins and modified my /etc/vimrc always from my user account with prepended `sudo`, but it seems like it was not that efficient. All things redone as `root` helped.